# Error when convert to Boolean matrix

Tags: ocaml

I have this problem still bother me a lots. I have a `(string * string list) list` and I want to convert it to Boolean matrix.

I have a special condition when transform it. For example I have this list:

```
let entries = [("name", ["string"; "label"]); ("label", ["int"; "name"]); 
               ("symbol", ["string"])]
```

where "`string`" and "`int`" are undefined type, undefined type because in my real data, I don't have a definition describe this type. So I built a list of undefined type.

```
let undefined = ["string"; "int"]
```

And the first position in the list ("`name`", "`label`", "`symbol`") are defined type, defined type is the type I have definition in my data.

```
let defined = ["name"; "label"; "symbol"]
```

I am trying to do this: from `entries`, there position should be:

```
name: 2; string: 0; label: 3; int: 1; symbol: 4
```

And when showing the depend relation from the list `entries`, it doesn't change their position. For example: `name(2)` link to `string(0)` and `label(3)`, and `label (3)` has an edge to `int(1)` and `name (2)`,` and so on...

I have these functions return a position(`num_of_name`) and element (`name_of_num`) in a list.

```
let rec position x = function
| [] -> raise Not_found
| y :: ys -> if x = y then 0 else 1 + position x ys

let len_undefined = List.length undefined

let num_of_name defined undefined len_undefined s =
  try (position s defined) + len_undefined;
  with Not_found -> position s undefined

let name_of_num defined undefined len_undefined k =
  if k < len_undefined then
    List.nth undefined k else
    List.nth defined (k - len_undefined)
```

So from the `entries` list I want to build a boolean matrix show there relation using the function `num_of_name`. So I write my function:

```
let matrix =
  let len = List.length defined + len_undefined in
  let boolmat = Array.make_matrix len len false in
  List.iter (fun (s, strs) ->
    let pos1 = num_of_name defined undefined len_undefined s in
      List.iter (fun t ->
    let pos2 = num_of_name defined undefined len_undefined t in
    boolmat.(pos1).(pos2) <- true) strs) entries;
    boolmat

let print_mat m =
  for i = 0 to Array.length m - 1 do
    for j = 0 to Array.length m.(0) - 1 do
      print_string (string_of_bool m.(i).(j));
      Printf.printf " ";
    done;
    Printf.printf " \n";
  done;
;;

let test_print = print_mat matrix
```

It return an error "`Fatal error: exception Not_found`"

I need your help.
Thank you very much!!

Comment: Could you explain what you want to do? What are the roles of `undefined` and `defined`?

Comment: Really?? I tried to run again and it return for me the same error.

Comment: undefined type because in my real data, I don't have a definition describe this type. And defined type is the type I have definition in my data.

Comment: Your `name_of_num` function is unused. And your test code runs fine on my machine. Are you sure you're running the same code posted here?

Comment: You are right, name_of_num is I am trying to show their relations convert from int -> string and string -> int. I am sure. I run again but it still problems. I added more information explains more details about what I want.

Comment: Ok, I found a bug in the code in my machine !

Comment: If there is a string somewhere in `entries` not belonging to either `defined` or `undefined`, the exception happens. Otherwise, your code is correct.

Comment: I put it as an answer which includes my suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comment, your `num_of_name` function is fragile since it throws `Not_found` exception when its input is not an element of either `defined` or `undefined`. One way to fix is using `Option` type:

```
let num_of_name defined undefined len_undefined s =
  try 
      let p = position s defined in
      Some (p + len_undefined)
  with Not_found -> 
     try
       let p = position s undefined in
       Some p
     with Not_found -> None
```

and `matrix` is calculated as:

```
let matrix =
  let len = List.length defined + len_undefined in
  let boolmat = Array.make_matrix len len false in
  List.iter (fun (s, strs) ->
    match num_of_name defined undefined len_undefined s with
    | Some pos1 -> List.iter (fun t ->
                      match num_of_name defined undefined len_undefined t with
                      | Some pos2 -> boolmat.(pos1).(pos2) <- true
                      | None -> ()) strs
    | None -> ()
      ) entries; 
  boolmat
```

Of course, if you enforce your program by extracting `defined` and `undefined` from `entries`, your code is correct.