# Print equivalence classes in Coq format

Tags: ocaml

Follow the counter example from my previous question: [Error when convert to Boolean matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8801316/error-when-convert-to-boolean-matrix) .

```
let entries = [("name", ["string"]); ("label", ["nonNegativeInteger"; "symbol"]);
("symbol", ["name"; "symbol"; "symbol"; "label"]); ("var", ["string"]);
("term", ["var"; "symbol"; "term"]); ("rule", ["term"; "term"]);
("rules", ["rule"]); ("dps", ["rules"]); ("trs", ["rules"]);
("usableRules", ["rules"]);
("number", ["integer"; "integer"; "positiveInteger"]);
("coefficient",["number"; "minusInfinity"; "plusInfinity"; "vector"; "matrix"])
("vector", ["coefficient"]); ("matrix", ["vector"])]

let defined = ["name"; "label"; "symbol"; "var"; "term"; "rule"; "rules"; 
"dps"; "trs"; "usableRules"; "number"; "coefficient"; "vector"; "matrix"]

let undefined = ["string"; "nonNegativeInteger"; "integer"; "positiveInteger";
"minusInfinity"; "plusInfinity"]
```

I computed with these functions: (more details please see here: [Transitive closure and equivalence classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678948/transitive-closure-and-equivalence-classes) and [Asking about return type, list and set data structure in OCaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8398072/asking-about-return-type-list-and-set-data-structure-in-ocaml))

```
let rec position x = function
| [] -> raise Not_found
| y :: ys -> if x = y then 0 else 1 + position x ys

let len_undefined = List.length undefined

let num_of_name xsds undefined len_undefined s =
  try (position s xsds) + len_undefined;
  with Not_found -> position s undefined

let name_of_num xsds undefined len_undefined k =
  if k < len_undefined then
    List.nth undefined k else
    List.nth xsds (k - len_undefined)

let matrix =
  let len = List.length defined + len_undefined in
  let boolmat = Array.make_matrix len len false in
  List.iter (fun (s, strs) ->
    let pos1 = num_of_name defined undefined len_undefined s in
      List.iter (fun t ->
    let pos2 = num_of_name defined undefined len_undefined t in
    boolmat.(pos1).(pos2) <- true) strs) entries;
    boolmat

let transClosure m =
  let n = Array.length m in
  for k = 0 to n - 1 do
    let mk = m.(k) in
    for i = 0 to n - 1 do
      let mi = m.(i) in
      for j = 0 to n - 1 do
    mi.(j) <- max mi.(j) (min mi.(k) mk.(j))
      done;
    done;
  done;
  m;;

let eq_class m i =
  let column = m.(i)
  and set = ref [] in
  Array.iteri begin fun j l ->
    if j = i || column.(j) && m.(j).(i) then
      set := j :: !set else ignore l
  end column;
  !set;;

let eq_classes m =
  let classes = ref [] in
  Array.iteri begin fun e _ ->
    if not (List.exists (List.mem e) !classes) then
      classes := eq_class m e :: !classes
  end m;
  !classes;;

let cmp_classes m c c' = if c = c' then 0 else
  match c, c' with
    | i :: _, j :: _ -> if m.(i).(j) then 1 else -1
    | _ -> assert false

let sort_eq_classes m = List.sort (cmp_classes m);;

let order_xsds =
  let tc_xsds = transClosure matrix in
  let eq_xsds = eq_classes tc_xsds in
  let sort_eq_xsds = sort_eq_classes tc_xsds eq_xsds in
  sort_eq_xsds

let print =
let f elem =
  print_int elem ; print_string " "
in List.iter f (List.flatten order_xsds);;

let xsds_of_int =
  List.map (List.map (name_of_num defined undefined len_undefined))

let xsds_sort = xsds_of_int order_xsds

let print_string =
let f elem =
  print_string elem ; print_string " \n"
in List.iter f (List.flatten xsds_sort);;
```

I try to print the result to see the sorted equivalence classes :

```
var name symbol label plusInfinity minusInfinity positiveInteger integer number 
matrix vector coefficient nonNegativeInteger string term rule rules usableRules 
trs dps
```

Because I have to print in Coq format, I have to make the file output combine, so the result I want to print in order of the results of the equivalence classes, when it see an equivalence classes ("label" -"symbol"; "coefficient" - "matrix" - "vector") it should print:

**EDIT:**

```
Inductive label := all the type label depends
with symbol := all the type symbol depends.
```

For example:

```
   Inductive label :=
    | Label : nonNegativeInteger -> symbol -> label
   with symbol :=
    | Symbol : name -> symbol -> symbol -> label -> symbol.
```

when it is one type depends it will print for me, for example:

```
Definition name := string.
```

and when it is more than 2 depends type,

```
Inductive numer := all the type number depends.
```

for example:

```
Inductive number := 
 |Number : integer -> integer -> positiveInteger -> number.
```

I think the list of type in `undefined` type should print before and after it will print in the result of the list after sorted (and **all the type of `undefined` list should not print** again), for example the result I expect like this:

```
Definition string := string.
Definition nonNegative := int.
...
Definition var := string.
Definition name := string.
Inductive label := ...
with symbol := ...
```

and so on

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

I might be confused but I think you're just looking for the [Printf](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Printf.html) module and `String.concat`?  e.g.

```
List.iter
    (fun name ->
        Printf.printf "Definition %s := %s.\n" name (defn_of name))
    undefined;
List.iter
    (fun eqvclass ->
        Printf.printf "Inductive %s.\n"
            (String.concat "\nwith "
                (List.map
                    (fun name ->
                        Printf.sprintf "%s := %s" name (defn_of name))
                    eqvclass)))
    order_xsds
```

(where `defn_of` gives you the right-hand side of the definitions).